# assign executables to specific coordinates in MPI Cartesian topology

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I want to assign every executable to specific coordinates in Cartesian
topology. Please consider an example and a Makefile. I compile executables
`main[0-7]` and run them using a command:

```
mpiexec \
-np 1 ./main0 : -np 1 ./main1 : \
-np 1 ./main2 : -np 1 ./main3 : \
-np 1 ./main4 : -np 1 ./main5 : \
-np 1 ./main6 : -np 1 ./main7
```

If I sort the output `make run | sort -g` it always returns:

```
N, rank, coords[3]: 0 0   0 0 0
N, rank, coords[3]: 1 1   0 0 1
N, rank, coords[3]: 2 2   0 1 0
N, rank, coords[3]: 3 3   0 1 1
N, rank, coords[3]: 4 4   1 0 0
N, rank, coords[3]: 5 5   1 0 1
N, rank, coords[3]: 6 6   1 1 0
N, rank, coords[3]: 7 7   1 1 1
```

Here `N` is an id of an executable. It seems work as I want: `main0`
goes to coordinates `(0, 0, 0)`, `main1` goes to coordinates `(0, 0, 1)` and
so on. Does the standard fix this arrangment?

**Makefile**

```
all: main0 main1 main2 main3 main4 main5 main6 main7

cc=mpicc
main0: main.c; $(cc) -DN=0 $< -o $@
main1: main.c; $(cc) -DN=1 $< -o $@
main2: main.c; $(cc) -DN=2 $< -o $@
main3: main.c; $(cc) -DN=3 $< -o $@
main4: main.c; $(cc) -DN=4 $< -o $@
main5: main.c; $(cc) -DN=5 $< -o $@
main6: main.c; $(cc) -DN=6 $< -o $@
main7: main.c; $(cc) -DN=7 $< -o $@

run: all
    mpiexec \
    -np 1 ./main0 : -np 1 ./main1 : \
    -np 1 ./main2 : -np 1 ./main3 : \
    -np 1 ./main4 : -np 1 ./main5 : \
    -np 1 ./main6 : -np 1 ./main7

clean:; rm -f main[0-7]
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define ndims 3
int rank, coords[ndims];
int    dims[ndims] = {2, 2, 2};
int periods[ndims] = {0, 0, 0};
int reorder = 0;
MPI_Comm cart;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ndims, dims, periods, reorder,   &cart);

  MPI_Comm_rank(cart,   &rank);
  MPI_Cart_coords(cart, rank, ndims,   coords);
  printf("N, rank, coords[3]: %d %d   %d %d %d\n", N, rank, coords[0], coords[1], coords[2]);

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the standard fix this arrangment?

Yes.

If you use `mpiexec`<sup>1</sup> with the following form:

```
mpiexec { <above arguments> } : { ... } : { ... } : ... : { ... }
```

*8.8 Portable MPI Process Startup* says it corresponds to `MPI_COMM_SPAWN_MULTIPLE`.

In turn,

> Their ranks in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` correspond directly to the order in which the commands are specified in `MPI_COMM_SPAWN_MULTIPLE`. Assume that m<sub>1</sub> processes are generated by the first command, m<sub>2</sub> by the second, etc. The processes corresponding to the first command have ranks *0, 1, . . . , m<sub>1</sub> −1*. The processes in the second command have ranks *m<sub>1</sub> , m<sub>1</sub> +1, . . . , m<sub>1</sub> + m<sub>2</sub> − 1*. The processes in the third have ranks *m<sub>1</sub> + m<sub>2</sub> , m<sub>1</sub> + m<sub>2</sub> + 1, . . . , m<sub>1</sub> + m<sub>2</sub> + m<sub>3</sub> − 1*, etc.

That gives you a consistent mapping from command line to `MPI_COMM_WORLD` rank. *7.2 Virtual Topologies* then gives you the mapping to the coordinates:

> Process coordinates in a Cartesian structure begin their numbering at 0. Row-major numbering is always used for the processes in a Cartesian structure.

That said, the approach of compiling a different binary for each rank that just differs by one macro seems silly and not quite elegant.

<sup>1: The sepcifications only apply to `mpiexec`, not `mpirun`. MPI implementations are not required to provide `mpiexec`.</sup>